# Using an empty clearing div to force the container enclosing floated elements to stretch: is it considered good style?

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-float, compatibility

I would like to draw your attention to the following example. In wrapperA, the block-level header element which encloses the two floats is forced to stretch to the full height of the enclosed floats (in a more general situation, it would stretch to the sum of the tallest of the two, or to a sum of heights of tallest floats if they did not fit within header and ended up being stacked on several rows of floated divs). The element forcing this stretch is the  element.
Thanks to this element, if we want wrapperA to enclose the floats within it, setting the height
(or in more general situation summing a sum of maximum heights of floated elements) on the wrapperA
element is redundant.

**Is this considered a good technique, when we need to stretch a non-floated container to its contained floated elements (so that its background, in this case magenta, becomes visible)?**

Note that in the wrapperB code, the header element does not enclose the floated elements which appear inside it in the html, because the header element is laid out in normal flow, and the
floated elements are laid out in floated-flow. Since elements in floated flow are removed
from the normal flow, the height of wrapperB is zero. Nevertheless, we can still cause
the  element to appear below the floats, and not at the very top,
by making use of the "clear: both" style on such bottom element.

> IMAGE 1:

[image]

> CODE FOR IMAGE 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>How to use a clearing div.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapperA" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background: black;">
    <header style="background: magenta;">
      <div id="oneA" style="float: left; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: yellow;">
      </div>
      <div id="twoA" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: cyan;">
      </div>
      <div id="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="bottomA" style="clear: both; height: 50px; background: green;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="spacer" style="width: 400px; height: 20px; background: red; text-align: center;">
    Space between WrapperA and WrapperB
  </div>
  <div id="wrapperB" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background: black;">
    <header style="background: magenta;">
      <div id="oneB" style="float: left; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: yellow;">
      </div>
      <div id="twoB" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: cyan;">
      </div>
      <!--
      <div id="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
      -->
    </header>
    <div id="bottomB" style="clear: both; height: 50px; background: green;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if this "clear: both;" style were not specified on bottomB, then bottomB
would of course appear at the very top of wrapperB, just below the zero-height header,
as in the following picture (with the floats stacked above it):

> IMAGE 2:

[image]

> CODE FOR IMAGE2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>How to use a clearing div.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapperB" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background: black;">
    <header style="background: magenta;">
      <div id="oneB" style="float: left; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: yellow;">
      </div>
      <div id="twoB" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: cyan;">
      </div>
      <!--
      <div id="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
      -->
    </header>
    <div id="bottomB" style="height: 50px; background: green;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The other thing that can be done in this situation is of course to float the header,
for instance we could float it left, or right, which makes no difference as long as
we also specify its width so that it is as wide as the wrapper element which contains
it (so that it does not shrink horizontally to the width of the float elements it contains).
However, in this case the header container gets floated on top of bottomB. To avoid this,
we must apply the "clear: both;" style on bottomB. HOWEVER, WITH THIS TECHNIQUE WE MUST
REMEMBER THAT ANY MARGINS SPECIFIED ON THE DIV BELOW THE UPPER FLOATED SIBLING, WILL
COLLAPSE TO ZERO, just as the following margin-top of the ludicrous 1000000px;
colapses to zero:

> IMAGE3:

[image]

> CODE FOR IMAGE3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>How to use a clearing div.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapperC" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background: black;">
    <header style="float: left; width: 400px; background: magenta; margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <div id="oneC" style="float: left; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: yellow;">
      </div>
      <div id="twoC" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: cyan;">
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="bottomC" style="clear: both; height: 50px; background: green; margin-top: 1000000px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I would like to know which of these three techniques works best across all browsers,
possibly going as back as to include IE6 and "quirks mode" browsers.**

Thanks!